# Integrating a function to find a constant

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

`PDF of a random variable X:
f(x) = b*x(1-x)^3 for x[0,1].`

The question I need to answer is: `Use the the integrate function to show that 'b' = 20.`

I tried the following:

`fx<-function(b,x){
  b*x*(1-x)^3
}
integrate(fx, 0,1)`

However, I get the following message:

`Error in f(x, ...) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Well, `?integrate`'s description says it works on "functions of one variable", and your function has two variables... Maybe you should just set `b = 20` and show that that solution works.

Comment: What is the software you are forced to use to do this basic math?

Comment: Cause you get b* integral(-x^3+3x^2-2x+1)dx=b*(-x^4/4+x^3-x^2+x) which must have some cfd property on interval [0,1], thus constraining b. No software really needed but I guess point is to learn the software? Is it called r?

Comment: @marshalcraft: It seems pretty clear that this is a question about R, the programming language. The question is correctly tagged and contains recognisable R code.

Comment: @Marius: Well I was answering additional parts that were provided. The question wasn't just how to integrate a single variable polynomial in 'r', was it? Which seems to be what is really sought in which case it makes this a poor question as that seems an elementary 'r' task. Perhaps 5 minutes of reading a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to *show* that b=20 for the integral to be 1, can you just do this?

```
> my.fxn <- function(x) 20*x*(1-x)^3
> integrate(my.fxn,0,1)
1 with absolute error < 1.1e-14
```

Alternatively, you can show that the limit when b->20 of the integral from 0 to 1 is 1; admittedly quick and dirty but not sure exactly what your overall goal is.

```
> my.fxn <- function(x) 19*x*(1-x)^3
> integrate(my.fxn,0,1)
0.95 with absolute error < 1.1e-14

> my.fxn <- function(x) 19.5*x*(1-x)^3
> integrate(my.fxn,0,1)
0.975 with absolute error < 1.1e-14

> my.fxn <- function(x) 20.5*x*(1-x)^3
> integrate(my.fxn,0,1)
1.025 with absolute error < 1.1e-14

> my.fxn <- function(x) 21*x*(1-x)^3
> integrate(my.fxn,0,1)
1.05 with absolute error < 1.2e-14
```

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. I also a bit confused about the question.

Comment: @mysteRious  Why so complicated? Define `f <- function(x,b) b*x*(1-x)^3` and calculate e.g. `integrate(f,0,1,b=19)`. Then you don't have to redefine function `my.fxn`  for every value of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Define

```
f <- function(x) x*(1-x)^3
```

then since the integral of a PDF must be 1 the value for `b` can calculated from

```
b <- 1/integrate(f,0,1)$value
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error in f(x, ...) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

You can set the default value as

```
fx <- function( b , x = 1  ){
  b*x*(1-x)^3
}
```

Try it [here](http://rextester.com/live/KLGI2577)